# Perl: struct-like storage of data

Tags: linux, perl

I have an existing perl script which I have to modify. For this, I need some struct-like container for my data. I do not have any 'outside' modules, nor do I possess the capability to obtain them, and my perl is 5.8.8. I've written a package containing one var and two arrays for my needs, however I cannot get it to work and I am not sure why. Here it is:

```
{
    package TestData;

    sub new
    {
        my $class = shift;
        my $self = {
          _id          => shift,
          _genUsers    => [],
          _testSymbols => [],
        };
        return bless ($self, $class);
    }

    sub setId
    {
        my ($self, $id) = @_;
        $self->{_id} = $id if defined($id);
    }

    sub addGenUser
    {
        my ($self, $user) = @_;
        push @{$self->{_genUsers}}, $user;
    }

    sub addTestSymbol
    {
        my ($self, $sym) = @_;
        push @{$self->{_testSymbols}}, $sym;
    }

    sub getId
    {
        my $self = @_;
        return $self->{_id};
    }

    sub getGenUserList
    {
        my $self = @_;
        return @{$self->{_genUsers}};
    }

    sub getTestSymbolList
    {
        my $self = @_;
        return @{$self->{_testSymbols}};
    }
}

use strict;
use POSIX;

my $id = "test";

my @a;
push @a, "this";

my @b;
push @b, "that";


my $obj = new TestData($id, @a, @b);
print "DEBUG: " . $obj->getId() . "\n";
```

Last line always throws "use of uninitialized value". What's going on?

Also would it be possible to do something like this:

```
my @c;
push @c, $obj;
foreach(@c){
    print "DEBUG2: " . $_->getId() . "\n";
}
```

Thank you.

EDIT: Thank you everyone for your replies. This is what the fully working end result looked like:

```
{
    use strict;
    use POSIX;

    package TestData;

    sub new
    {
        my $class = shift;
        my $self = {
          _alpha        => shift,
          _beta         => shift,
          _gamma        => shift,
          _delta        => shift,
          _theta        => shift
        };
        return bless ($self, $class);
    }

    sub getAlpha
    {
        my $self = shift;
        return $self->{_alpha};
    }

    sub getBeta
    {
        my $self = shift;
        return $self->{_beta};
    }

    sub getGamma
    {
        my $self = shift;
        return $self->{_gamma};
    }

    sub getDelta
    {
        my $self = shift;
        return $self->{_delta};
    }

    sub getTheta
    {
        my $self = shift;
        return $self->{_theta};
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you've posted does not compile.  Your opening brace is backwards, and you've missed a `$` in `my id`.  Please fix your code so that it compiles.

Comment: The usefulness of your Perl installation is very limited if you cannot make use of additional library modules: one of Perl's major strengths is the huge amount of code that the community has made available for free. What is the reason that you can't use non-core modules? Is it a policy decision by the company you work for, or do you simply not know how to do it?

Comment: "I do not have any 'outside' modules, nor do I possess the capability to obtain them, and my perl is 5.8.8." - you should really work on fixing those problems first :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is in the line(s) that read:

```
my $self = @_;
```

This is a scalar assignment, and so assigns the *length* on `@_` to `$self`.  Trying to use the length as a hash reference then gives the "use of uninitialized value" warning you see, and returns `undef`.

By the way, in addition to enabling warnings, you should get into the habit of starting all your scripts and modules with `use strict;`.  If you'd done that, it would've caught this bug, and you would've received a runtime error saying something like:

```
Can't use string ("1") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at foo.pl line 36.
```

Anyway, to fix your code, you should replace the line above with either:

```
my ($self) = @_;
```

or:

```
my $self = shift;
```

or even:

```
my $self = $_[0];
```

With `my ($self) = @_` the parentheses turn it into a list assignment; with `my $self = shift` it's still a scalar assignment, but [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) (which, inside a `sub`, is shorthand for `shift @_`) pulls the first scalar out of `@_`.

The choice of which style to prefer basically comes down to personal taste and consistency; if you're used to pulling all your method args out of `@_` with a single assignment like:

```
my ($self, $foo, $bar, $baz) = @_;
```

then, for methods that take no arguments other than `$self`, a single-element list assignment seems more consistent.  On the other hand, if you prefer to pick your args out of `@_` one at a time, as in:

```
my $self = shift;
my $foo  = shift;
my $bar  = shift;
my $baz  = shift;
```

the you obviously should follow that pattern for single-arg methods too.

Comment: The OP did `use strict`, but not until after the block which defines the TestData package, so it only applied to the procedural code at the end, not to the package definition. Which is why `use strict` should generally be the very first line of Perl code in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Change

> my $self = @_;

to

> my $self = shift;

in your methods that only expect one argument and especifically the called one (i.e.):

```
  sub getId
    {
        my $self = shift;
        return $self->{_id};
    }
```

You can also wrap the $self around parentheses to change context and do the same thing as commented

Output:

```
DEBUG: test
```

Comment: +1. `my ($self) = @_;`, with parentheses around `$self`, would also work (because the parens make it a list assignment), but `my $self = @_;` assigns the *length* of `@_` to `$self` (because without them it's a scalar assignment, and an array in scalar context evaluates to its length).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than roll your own, you might want to check out `Class::Struct`, which has been part of Perl's core since 5.4.

Comment: Cannot use it. The Perl @inc cannot find it, and I'm not sure why since I didn't set up my machine.

Comment: What OS are you running?